# Por qué sigue contando?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un pequeño programa en **JavaScript** y se supone que cuando cualquiera de los jugadores llega a 3 VICTORIAS, sus victorias se reinician a 0, pero esto sucede solo aveces, porqué sucede esto?

```js
var maquinaGanadas = 0; // MÁQUINA
  var tuGanadas = 0; // JUGADOR

function contar() {
  
  
  var maquinaN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var tuN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  
  
  document.getElementById("tunumero").innerHTML = tuN + '\n';
   var c = document.getElementById("tunumero");
   c.setAttribute("style", "color: blue;");
  
  document.getElementById("numeromaquina").innerHTML = maquinaN;
   var d = document.getElementById("numeromaquina");
   d.setAttribute("style", "color: red;");
   
   if(tuN > maquinaN) {
    
    document.getElementById("numeroG").innerHTML = "\n" + "TÚ !"    
    tuGanadas++;
   }
   else if(tuN < maquinaN) {
    
    document.getElementById("numeroG").innerHTML = "\n" + "MÁQUINA !"    
    maquinaGanadas++
   }
   else {
    
    
    document.getElementById("numeroG").innerHTML = "\n" + "EEEMPATE !!"    
   }
   if (tuGanadas == 3) {
    
    document.getElementById("numeroG").innerHTML = "\n" + "HAS GANADO LAS 3 RONDAS! FELICIDADES"    
    
   }
   else if (maquinaGanadas == 3) {
    
    document.getElementById("numeroG").innerHTML = "\n" + "LA MÁQUINA HA ALCANZADO 3 VICTORIAS :("    
    
    
   }
   else if (maquinaGanadas == 3 || tuGanadas == 3) {maquinaGanadas = 0; tuGanadas = 0;} // ACA SE REINICIAN LAS VICTORIAS <<<
   
   var todase = tuGanadas + maquinaGanadas;
   
   document.getElementById("totalestu").innerHTML = tuGanadas;
   document.getElementById("todas").innerHTML = todase;
   document.getElementById("totalesmaquina").innerHTML = maquinaGanadas;
  }
```

```html
  <div style="background-color: pink; width: 300px; height: 300px; position: relative;" id="numeros"><center><h3>EL PRIMERO EN GANAR 3 VECES , GANA LA PARTIDA !</h3></center><center><input type="button" onclick="contar()" value="JUGAR RULETA !"></center><i>Tu numero es </i><i id="tunumero"></i>y el número de la máquina es: <i id="numeromaquina"></i><hr></hr><b>Y EL GANADOR ES:</b> <i id="numeroG"></i><hr></hr><i>VICTORIAS TOTALES: </i><i id="todas"></i> <hr></hr><b> TUS VICTORIAS: </b><i id="totalestu"></i><hr></hr><b>VICTORIAS MAQUINA: </b><i id="totalesmaquina"></i></div>
```

Comment: Nunca va a llegar a else if (maquinaGanadas == 3 || tuGanadas == 3) por los 'if's anterior. Debes reiniciar en tuGanadas == 3 o maquinaGanadas == 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque es imposible llegar a esta parte del codigo

```
 else if (maquinaGanadas == 3 || tuGanadas == 3) {maquinaGanadas = 0; tuGanadas = 0;}
```

La manera de ingresar a ese `else if` es que cualquiera de las 2 condiciones sea `true` **pero** no hayas ingresado en algún `if` anterior

Los 2 `if` anteriores son:

```
 if (tuGanadas == 3)


 else if (maquinaGanadas == 3)
```

por lo que ingresarias en alguno de ellos y no en el que reinicializa las variables

Una opcion seria llevar el reseteo a los 2 `ifs` anteriores, pero dado que te interesa mostrar el valor "3" y reinicializarlo posteriormente a ello puedes volver a chequear al final si alguna de las dos variables son 3

Tu codigo quedaria asi (la modificacion esta al final):

```js
  var maquinaGanadas = 0; // MÁQUINA
      var tuGanadas = 0; // JUGADOR

    function contar() {


      var maquinaN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      var tuN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);


      document.getElementById("tunumero").innerHTML = tuN + '\n';
       var c = document.getElementById("tunumero");
       c.setAttribute("style", "color: blue;");

      document.getElementById("numeromaquina").innerHTML = maquinaN;
       var d = document.getElementById("numeromaquina");
       d.setAttribute("style", "color: red;");

       if(tuN > maquinaN) {

           document.getElementById("numeroG").innerHTML = "\n" + "TÚ !"    
           tuGanadas++;
       }
       else if(tuN < maquinaN) {

           document.getElementById("numeroG").innerHTML = "\n" + "MÁQUINA !"       
           maquinaGanadas++
       }
       else {


           document.getElementById("numeroG").innerHTML = "\n" + "EEEMPATE !!"     
       }
       if (tuGanadas == 3) {

           document.getElementById("numeroG").innerHTML = "\n" + "HAS GANADO LAS 3 RONDAS! FELICIDADES"    

       }
       else if (maquinaGanadas == 3) {

           document.getElementById("numeroG").innerHTML = "\n" + "LA MÁQUINA HA ALCANZADO 3 VICTORIAS :("      


       }


       var todase = tuGanadas + maquinaGanadas;

       document.getElementById("totalestu").innerHTML = tuGanadas;
       document.getElementById("todas").innerHTML = todase;
       document.getElementById("totalesmaquina").innerHTML = maquinaGanadas;

        if (maquinaGanadas == 3 || tuGanadas == 3) {maquinaGanadas = 0; tuGanadas = 0;} // ACA SE REINICIAN LAS VICTORIAS <<<
      }
```

```html
<div style="background-color: pink; width: 300px; height: 300px; position: relative;" id="numeros"><center><h3>EL PRIMERO EN GANAR 3 VECES , GANA LA PARTIDA !</h3></center><center><input type="button" onclick="contar()" value="JUGAR RULETA !"></center><i>Tu numero es </i><i id="tunumero"></i>y el número de la máquina es: <i id="numeromaquina"></i><hr></hr><b>Y EL GANADOR ES:</b> <i id="numeroG"></i><hr></hr><i>VICTORIAS TOTALES: </i><i id="todas"></i> <hr></hr><b> TUS VICTORIAS: </b><i id="totalestu"></i><hr></hr><b>VICTORIAS MAQUINA: </b><i id="totalesmaquina"></i></div>
```